# Git push tag from/to a current branch

Tags: git, tags, push, branch

I am currently working on a git branch and I added a tag to the existing last commit+push. Now I want to push the tag and use its name "v1.0". When I use

```
git push v1.0
```

I get the error message

```
fatal: 'v1.0' does not appear to be a git repository
```

That's correct, it is not a repository, it is a tag. The git doc says "git push origin v1.0". But I do not want to push to master, but to current branch. So, what do I have to change? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag and a branch don't have direct relationship. `git push origin v1.0` does not have anything to do with `master` or any other branch. The tag points to a commit. It does not care which branch the commit is reachable from. The commit may be on `master` and/or on another branch but it's none of the tag's business. With `git push origin v1.0`, it checks if the commit pointed by the tag, and all of its ancestors, exist in the remote repository. If some of them don't, then they are uploaded. Besides, a tag named `refs/tags/v1.0` will always be created in the remote repository too if it does not exist yet. It points to the same commit as it does in the local repository.

Comment: Thanks. That information I missed so far in the documentations I've found